# Tensor Algebra of Direct Sum

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, algebras

If $A$ is a $k$-algebra, and $(T(M), j_M)$ denotes the tensor algebra of an $A$-bimodule $M$, $j_M: M \to T(M)$ the associated homomorphism of $A$-bimodules, how can I prove that
$$T(M \oplus N)\cong T(M) \otimes_AT(N) $$

as $k$-algebras? I tried the following: define an homomorphism of  $f:M \oplus N \to T(M) \otimes_AT(N)$ by $f(m,n)=j_M(m) \otimes j_N(n)$. Then, there is an unique homomorphism (of $k$-algebras and $A$-bimodules) $\bar{f}:T(M \oplus N) \to T(M) \otimes_AT(N)$ such that $\bar{f} \circ j_{M \oplus N}=f$.

Any ideas how to define an inverse $\bar{g}:T(M) \otimes_AT(N) \to T(M \oplus N)$?

Comment: You just need to observe that the isomorphisms $V^n\otimes W^n \to (V\otimes W)^n$ sending $(v,w)$ to the "interleaving" of $v$ and $w$ are compatible with the product.

Comment: The homomorphism is surjective but not injective (except in trivial cases). For example, if $A = k$ and $M,N$ are one-dimensional $k$-vector spaces generated by $x,y$ respectively then $x \otimes y$ and $y \otimes x$ are different elements of $T(M \otimes N)$ which are mapped to the same element $x \otimes y$ of $T(M) \otimes_k T(N)$. In fact, $T(M) \otimes_k T(N)$ is naturally identified with $k[x] \otimes_k k[y] \cong k[x,y]$ which is the polynomial algebra in two **commuting** variables while $T(M \otimes N)$ is the polynomial algebra $k\left<x,y\right>$ in two non-commuting variables.

Comment: Alternatively, one can use the universal property of the tensor algebra: the $k$-algebra maps $T(M)\to R$ are in bijection with pairs $(f,g)$ such that $f\colon A\to R$ is a $k$-algebra mao, and $g\colon M\to R$ is an $A$-bimodule map (via $f$), so $g(ama’)=f(a)g(m)f(a’)$ for all $a,a’\in A$ and $m\in M$.